# Quality issues recording with Audacity

Tags: audio-recording, audacity, problem

I purchased an Audio Technica AT-LP60-USB turntable that came with Audacity software - version 2.0.3.
Here's the problem:    When I record music off any of my old albums using the Audacity program and then play it back, there is a 'skip' every 30 seconds. 
I am using a fairly new (2 years) HP lap top (8G of Ram, 700G hard drive) with Windows 7.
I have looked on-line and tried the specific set-ups that are recommended for the Audacity software to resolve this issue but I can't get rid of the problem.

Any ideas as to the cause and what I can do to eliminate this 'skipping'?